# getting residue of linear regression

Tags: c++, matlab, math, probability-distribution

if a Best Fit calculation routine finds Slope, intercept of linear regression of x and y, how to find residue?.

```
 - for (i=0;i<n;i++)
       y_fit[i]=Slope*x[i]+Intercept; 
   
   residue = sum of all (y[i]-y_fit[i])*(y[i]-y_fit[i])?.
```

Comment: Why not implementing a simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid using the `matlab`-tag if your question is with regards to `c++`.

In your case, a simple for-loop would do it

```
int residue = 0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     y_fit[i]=Slope*x[i]+Intercept; 
     residue += (y[i] - y_fit[i])*(y[i] - y_fit[i]);
}
```

Comment: Very true @Damien, thanks for pointing it out!